# Fetch specific record in foreach loop in php

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach, phpmyadmin

I want to fetch two record in foreach loop.

After fetch record, next two record for pagination

```
        $post_img_id=array(21,24,25,28,40,44,46,47,52,78,88,89,92,101);  //this is id of table data

        $total=count($post_img_id,COUNT_RECURSIVE); //total record

        $item=2;

        $total_page=ceil($total/$item);

        $cur_page=isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:1;

        $k=($cur_page-1)*$item;

                foreach($post_img_id as $id)
                {
                    if($co<=10){
                  $post_img_q="select * from $post where id=$id LIMIT $k,$item";
                  $post_img_res=mysql_query($post_img_q) or die(mysql_error());

                     while($post_img_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($post_img_res))
                     { 

                        echo 'record';
                     }
                }
        ?>
```

how to solve this problem ? please help me !

Thanx for Advance !

Comment: Please try and edit your question so it is CLEAR what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use array_chunk()
refer this link :http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

i.e : `print_r(array_chunk($post_img_id, 2, true));`

```
$nameofArray = array_chunk($post_img_id, 2, true);
foreach($nameofArray as $Array)
{
//your code here...
}
```

check this in your code its devide your array in portion of 2 where you will get array of 2 records so it will help you more easily to paginate record.

Comment: how to use in query ??

Comment: declare result from array_chunk into one variable and use foreach for it.

Comment: display error "Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'"

Comment: you does not take $array as column name you will get two records in $array this thing work like multidimensional array.

Comment: $nameofArray = array_chunk($post_img_id, 2, true);
     foreach($nameofArray as $id)
     {
      //print_r($id);
       $post_img_q="select * from $post where id_post=$id LIMIT $k,$item";
       $post_img_res=mysql_query($post_img_q) or die(mysql_error());
       
      while($post_img_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($post_img_res))
      { 
     }
     
    ?>

Comment: use like this : 
foreach($nameofArray as $array) 
 { //print_r($id); 

  foreach ($array as $key => $record) {
   # code...
   $post_img_q="select * from $post where id_post=$record LIMIT $k,$item"; 
   $post_img_res=mysql_query($post_img_q) or die(mysql_error()); 
   while($post_img_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($post_img_res)) { } 
  }
 }

Comment: all record are display